# add block programmatically

Tags: 6, hooks

How can i add a block from mymodule. The content for the block is a form which contain a dropdown listing the themes. I tried with the following code. but it is not working.

```
function mymodule_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0){
$block = array();
    switch ($op) {
     case 'list':
       $blocks['mymodule_preview'] = array(
      'info' => t('mymodule Preview'),
      'region' => t('header'),
      'weight' => 0,
      'status' => 1
  );
  return $blocks;
case 'view':
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'mymodule_preview':
      $block = array(
          'content' => mymodule_theme_form(),
      );
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
}


function mymodule_theme_form() {
global $custom_theme;
$themes = system_theme_data();
uasort($themes, 'tmymodule_sort_modules_by_info_name');
$themeOptions[] = 'Select';
$rolesOptions[] = 'Select';
foreach ($themes as $theme) {
    $themeOptions[$theme->name] = $theme->name;
}

// themes dropdown
$form1["themes"] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Preview the page with themes available'),
    '#options' => $themeOptions,
    '#default_value' => $custom_theme,
    '#attributes' => array('onchange' => "form.submit('themes')"),
);
//Submit button:
$form1['submit_'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit '),
        '#attributes' => array('style' => 'display: none;'),
);

return $form1;

}
```

This creates the block but content just prints "Array" only. 
i am using drupal 6 . 
 What is wrong in this code?  Pls help me

Comment: *It doesn't work* is a too broad statement that doesn't explain what does not work or in which way what you obtain is not what you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  $block = array(
      'content' => drupal_get_form('mymodule_theme_form'),
  );
```